Cannot forward USB device to Proxmox LXC as it changes ID every time it is unplugged
I am setting up a printer in a Debian LXC image on Proxmox. I identified the printer in lsusb:
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04f9:01ea Brother Industries, Ltd DCP-7030

and I forward it in Proxmox (device /dev/bus/usb/001/007).
As soon as I unplug the printer and plug it back in, it always gets a new ID, for example:
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f9:01ea Brother Industries, Ltd DCP-7030

The printer does not show up in /dev/serial/*.
There are three possible solutions I can think of:

Somehow fix the ID, such that I can forward it statically
Forward all USB devices
Reference the printer as a symlink (udev rule TTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="01ea", SYMLINK+="brother_printer" works, but CUPS/SANE are unable to detect it as a printer)

I am unsure which of these is the most promising path and how to proceed with it.

The ID is 04f9:01ea, and isn't changing.  The "Bus" (001), is which USB host device you connected it to.  The "Device" is a connection specific entry of how the system internally refers to this device.  It is expected to change, and can't be fixed.  You might be able to put  the forwarding into a udev rule, or write a script to parse the output if lsusb -d 04f9:01ea.  You might be able to forward it by 04f9:01ea (though maybe not as there could be two matching devices).

@DavidG. Thanks, that's a good idea. I see this option for VMs but not for LXC containers. Do you know how forwarding by VendorID/DeviceID works for containers?

Sorry, can't specifically help you there, but:  The LXC container's filesystem may be in your parent filesystem, allowing udev to write into it.  Mind you, a symlink probably wouldn't work as the container couldn't see the target  Instead you would need to make a device node.

@DavidG. Ok, I switched the entire system from LXC to a VM and now it all works great. Thanks for the hint
